# Would it be possible to use both a Razberry Z-Wave and a RaspBee simultaneously?

Tags: gpio, razberry

Both of these devices use the GPIO header. It looks as if each uses about half, and I'm wondering if it would just be a software modification to plug one or the other into the other half (or, if even both would fit... looks as if the RaZberry might overhang pins it's not using).

RaZberry (looks like 10 pins):

[image: RaZberry]

RaspBee (confirmed 12 pins from the page):

[image: RaspBee]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RaZberry uses only four pins: Vcc, Gnd, Tx, Rx. Unfortunatelly, 10 pins are covered by the pinholder, since Vcc and Gnd/Tx/Rx are in different corners, so this is more to keep the board stable on pins.

You can use unused pins just by soldering wires to RaZberry board or by breaking a bit the pinholder of RaZberry, releasing uneeded pins for other applications.

But Raspbee seems to also use serial port, so they can not work together.

But Raspberry Pi allows to use GPIO to use make more UART pins.

Answer (score 3):

By a quick look it seams that **Razberry** uses SPI and serial port, and that **Raspbee** uses serial port. Serial port is not shareable, so you would need to use **[two of them](http://lavalink.com/2012/04/more-on-raspberry-pi-serial-ports/)**, with a lot of hand made rewiring and changing software to enable using both at the same time.

Instead of all this mess, you might want to consider **[EVE](http://postscapes.com/meet-eve-rasberry-pi-wireless-development-hardware)**, a RPi wireless shield with connectors for **Zigbee**, **ZWave**, **EnOcean** and 433/868/915Mhz **RFM12B** module.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. The nice thing about the RaspBee is that it has an external antenna connector. But I'll take a look at EVE too.

Comment: You are wrong, RaZberry also uses UART to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using the Razberry from the USB. I bought a USB/UART dongle, and and wired it to the 3.3V, GND, TX and RX pins, and followed the instructions on this webpage: https://www.domotiga.nl/projects/domotiga/wiki/Z-Wave_RaZberry

It basically tells you how to use Razberry on a Cubieboard using UART.

With the Razberry using the USB, you can then use the Raspbee on the GPIO...